# How to lock a formula with self reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying this:

C9 formula: =-40+C9

What I want to is being able to enter some value in C9 that will not overwrite the formula and get a result in that cell. For example:

If I enter the value 140 in C9, the cell will display 100, because the formula is =-40+C9

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a macro for a cell change http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612
You may find useful to read this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change

Here's the working example (just tried it on my computer)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        isect.Value = isect.Value - 40
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so now I have:  `Sub Troca_Valor()
'
' Troca_Valor Macro
' Macro recorded 07/04/2013 by Fernando
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC-40"
    Range("C10").Select
End Sub`

Comment: I had to enter the function code in reply to my question, is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **no**.

Doing what you stated will cause what's called a [circular reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-HP010066243.aspx).

Comment: There must be a way, excel is so powerfull

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it!

Making C9 = -40 + C9 is simply a **recursion**. This means, if the cell is allowed to evaluate, it should keep subtracting -40 from itself forever.
Also, I don't recommend using Macro. You will never be able to make changes or revert back to the previous values. Say, if you want to change one cell, other cells will be affected to.

My suggestion is to make an extra column for this. Say write your value in C9 and evaluate that in D9. Then, you can go and **hide** the C column to make it non-printable. This way is very robust and safe. Actually, this is how spreadsheets are meant to work.